# Pandas row value string parsing (mixed string and float)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe imported from a csv and the raw data looks like this (a very simplified version - the original data has more than 100,000 rows and additional 10 components in the value column) :

| id1 | id2 | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | name=john, city=new york, age=33, result=1.01 |
| b | 2 | name=anna, city=paris, age=21, result=2.53 |

My objective is to modify the dataframe like this:

| id1 | id2 | name | city | age | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | john | new york | 33 | 1.01 |
| b | 2 | anna | paris | 21 | 2.53 |

I tried splitting the data from the "values" column using , and = but since the "values" column has mixed components including string and float, it is very confusing and I cannot make it work.
Any tips or help would be life saver. Thanks

Comment: Maybe `df.join(pd.DataFrame([dict([y.split('=') for y in x.split(',')]) for x in df.pop('values')]))` ?